# Python's shutil.make_archive() creates dot directory on Windows

Tags: python, windows, zip

Using `shutil.make_archive('newarchive', 'zip', <directory>)` to create a ZIP archive in Python 3.5 does not behave as expected on Windows.

On Linux it works correctly, all files and folders inside `directory` are archived and visible in the zip file. However, on Windows an extra folder is created - the dot folder `.`. See screenshot:

[image]

The folder itself is empty, but I want to get rid of it altogether (another process is very strict about the structure). A workaround would be not using `make_archive()` and manually create `ZipFile`, but I feel that the function should work in the first place.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

---

**Edit**: dot file is present in 7Zip as well as Total Commander.
This is the shortest working snippet for me (Python 3.5.1, Windows 10):

```
import shutil
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/melka/Downloads')
shutil.make_archive('testing', 'zip', 'zip_test')
```

This creates a new ZIP from contents of `C:\Users\melka\Downloads\zip_test`, which ends up being:
[image]

However, manually creating the zip using this code does not create the dot file:

```
import os
import zipfile


def make_zip(zip_name, path):
    zip_handle = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    os.chdir(path)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        for file in files:
            zip_handle.write(os.path.join(root, file))

os.chdir('C:/Users/melka/Downloads')
make_zip('anotherzip.zip', 'zip_test')
```

[image]

Comment: cannot reproduce (using python 2.7). Your command line is not correct btw. Are you sure it's not a problem of your graphical unarchiver? I'm using 7-zip and I don't see any dot dir.

Comment: It was not correct, only due to re-typing it here. I provided code samples that do not work for me. I am pretty sure, I tried opening using both Total Commander and 7Zip and the dot file was shown in both (when created via `make_archive`) -- when created via a custom function, it was not present in either unarchiver.

Comment: Try passing a logger to the `logger` argument for `shutil.make_archive`? May provide more information.

Comment: Same bug is under Linux, just copy the zip created on Linux to a Windows machine and you see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "bug" has been fixed in October 2016 : https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/666de7772708047b63125126b0147931571254a4

Here the diff :
[image]

Apparently, you need to update to either Python 3.5.3 or 3.6.

Comment: Update as a of Jan '18: The issue is also present with Python 3.4.7 on _Linux_. It was not the case before (<= 3.4.6, although I am not sure if it was introduced with 3.4.6, 3.4.5, or a slightly earlier release).